# Can someone help fix my opacity scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i place my div id tag #fading everything seems to fade at once.  I want my parts to fade one by one; individually.  I'm not so skilled at jquery, so some assistance would be great.

Part 1
                                
                                
                                    Part 2
                                
                                    
                                    Part 3
                                
                                    
                                    Part 4
                                
                                    
                                    Part 5

```
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>


    <div style="background:white;">
            <div class="row" id="fading" style="padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%;margin-top:100px;">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                <p><b><em>Part 1:</b></em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="./photo1.jfif" class="img-responsive ">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%;margin-top:150px;">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                <p><b><em>Part 2:</b></em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="./photo2.jpg" class="img-responsive ">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%;margin-top:200px;">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                <p><b><em>Part 3:</b></em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="./photo3.jfif" class="img-responsive ">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%;margin-top:250px;">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                <p><b><em>Part 4:</b></em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="./photo4.jfif" class="img-responsive ">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-left:15%; padding-right:15%;margin-top:300px;">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                <p><b><em>Part 5:</b></em> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="./photo5.jfif" class="img-responsive ">
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is the script that needs to be fixed or changed.

```
   <script>
var target = $('#fading');
var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e){
var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
if(scrollPercent >= 0){
    target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you might be after?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJomJY?editors=001

The script is now accounting for the scroll percentage on each `.row` element :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var posY = window.scrollY;

    $('.row').each(function(key, item) {

        var target = $(item);
        var topMargin = parseInt(target.css('margin-top'));
        var targetHeight = target.outerHeight(true);
        var targetStart = target.position().top;
        var targetEnd = targetStart+targetHeight;
        var scrollPercent = (targetEnd-posY)/targetHeight;
        scrollPercent = Math.max(0, Math.min(scrollPercent, 1));

        if (posY > targetStart-topMargin) {
            target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome of course. It's a nice effect that I'll have to keep in mind.Thanks for following up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try below query:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    $('.row').each(function(i, o) {

        var target = $(o);
        var targetHeight = target.outerHeight() + target.position().top;

        var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
        if(scrollPercent >= 0){
            target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
       }

    })
});
```

i hope it can help you!

Comment: This is better than the code I have, but once I get around Part 3 everything starts to fade at once.

Comment: Can be explained in detail under what kind of effect you want to do

Comment: As I scroll down, I went the parts with the picture to fade but not all at once. For instance, I scroll down, then part 1 only begins to fade leaving only the nav,heading, and 4 others parts. then scroll some more then part 2 begins to fade... and so on and so forth. What was happening in the code you gave me is that some of the parts were fading all at once, instead of one by one.